# Other uses of strtotime() in PHP

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm trying to get strtotime to make Date Ranges, I've already figured it out for some of the basic ones.

Here's some that i'm trying to figure out but I can't find the format that you're supposed to type anywhere online for these ones:

```
$startDate = strtotime('first day of last month');
$endDate = strtotime('last day of last month');
$startDate = strtotime('first of last week');
$startDate = strtotime('first of this week');
```

Those are the only ones I can't find a reference for, they might require special programming and don't have a `strtotime` reference.

Edit: Looks like my code should've worked but there's a bug in PHP 5.2

I used a workaround to get to the first day of last month.

This works: $firstDayOfLastMonth = strtotime(date('Y-m', strtotime('last month')))

Comment: I think some of these can be achieved with using a combination of date() and strtotime() for example the first day of last month would be something like `strtotime(date('Y-m') . ' - 1 month');`

Comment: Have a look here: [Supported Date and Time Formats: Relative Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: Your first two examples work fine for me, PHP 5.3.5

Answer (score 1):

For the week ones you can use

```
strtotime('this week midnight'); // returns Monday midnight of this week
strtotime('last week midnight'); // returns Monday midnight of last week
```

This works if you want the week starting on Monday. Last week seems to work with assumption that Monday is first day. If you want the timestamp for week starting on Sunday, use the following:

```
strtotime('last week Sunday midnight'); // returns Sunday midnight of this week
strtotime('-2 weeks Sunday midnight'); // returns Sunday midnight of last week
```